# window.getSelection() Does Not Work When Run Via JSNI and On IE

Tags: gwt, jsni

The following code works on Chrome and Firefox via JSNI and on all browsers in pure JavaScript, but not on IE via JSNI.

**GWT JSNI:**

```
    // windowEl is the contentWindow of an iframe
    protected native Element insertImage(String src, String title, String cssClassname, Element windowEl)
    /*-{
         var result = null;
         var selRanges = windowEl.getSelection();   // no ranges returned here on IE
         if (selRanges.rangeCount > 0) {
             var curRange = selRanges.getRangeAt(0);
             if (curRange.toString().length == 0) {
                 var imageNode = windowEl.document.createElement('img');
                 imageNode.src = src;
                 imageNode.alt = title;
                 imageNode.title = title;
                 imageNode.className = cssClassname;
                 curRange.insertNode(imageNode);
                 result = imageNode;
             }
         }
         return result;
     }-*/;
```

**JavaScript:**

```
 var myIframe = $doc.getElementById('my_iframe');
 var range = myIframe.contentWindow.getSelection().getRangeAt(0);
 var imageNode = myIframe.contentWindow.document.createElement('img');
 imageNode.src = 'goo.gl/Zun4LD';
 imageNode.alt = 'error';
 imageNode.title = 'error';
 imageNode.className = 'my_css_class';
 range.insertNode(imageNode);
```

The problem occurs when getSelection() returns nothing on IE when run via JSNI.

I am using GWT 2.7 & IE 10 to test.

Any ideas why this might be happening?  Is this a bug with GWT 2.7?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure that your iframe's contentWindow is not losing focus. IE can't deal with these situations as elegantly as others.

Try:

```
// windowEl is the contentWindow of an iframe
protected native Element insertImage(String src, String title, String cssClassname, Element windowEl)
/*-{
     var result = null;
     windowEl.focus();  // ***** add this to be sure you're not losing focus
     var selRanges = windowEl.getSelection();   // no ranges returned here on IE
     if (selRanges.rangeCount > 0) {
         ...
     }
     return result;
 }-*/;
```